# A form submission using JavaScript Validation

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

This is not working, I am new to PHP. When I run this PHP ,the values get passed to the second php without showing any blank space validation, I don't know what i did wrong.
I tried to write the code from looking at various tutorials online but don't know what went wrong.

```
  <html>
  <body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function validateForm(){
var w=document.forms["myForm"]["t1"].value;
  var x=document.forms["myForm"]["t2"].value;
var y=document.forms["myForm"]["t3"].value;
var z=document.forms["myForm"]["s1"].value;

    if (w==null || w=="")
   {
  alert("Fill out");
  return false;
  }
  if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("Fill out");
  return false;
  }
  if (y==null || y=="")
  {
  alert("Fill out");
  return false;
  }
  if (z==null || z=="")
  {
  alert("Fill out");
  return false;
  }
   }
   </script>
   </head>
  <body><form id="f1" method="post" action="2.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
   <h1>FORM</h1>
   <br>
   ID :<input type="text" id="t1" name="t1" />
    NAME :<input type="text" id="t2" name="t2" /><br>
    GENDER :
   MALE<input type="radio" id="t3" name="t3" value="MALE" />
   FEMALE<input type="radio" id="t3" name="t3" value="FEMALE"/>
   <br>COURSE
   <select name="s1" id="s1">
   <option value="B.tech">B.Tech</option>
   <option value="B.com">B.com</option>
   <option value="Bba">Bba</option>
    </select>
   <br>
   <input type="submit" id="b1" name= "b1" value="Login" />
   <input type="submit" id="b1" name= "b1" value="Cancel" />
    </form>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There actually 2 problems with your code.

**1.**
You are trying to retrieve the form element using `document.forms["myForm"]`, but there seems to be no form named 'myForm'. 
You should add:

```
...
<form ... name="myForm">
...
```

---

**2.**
You cannot get the value of a group of radio-buttons using the `.value` attribute. What you have to do is iterate through all elements of the group and see if the `checked` property is set.
The easiest way is to create a utility function for this (see below) and then call it:
var y = getRadioValue("myForm", "t3");

```
function getRadioValue(formName, groupName) {
    var value = "";
    var radioGroup = document.forms[formName][groupName];
    for (var i = 0; i < radioGroup.length; i++) {
        if (radioGroup[i].checked) {
            value = radioGroup[i].value;
            break;
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

If you are using jQuery, you can omit the function and just use the appropriate selector:

```
var y = $('input[name="t3"]:checked').val();
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/Gf76A/)**.

Comment: thanks for the solution and that solved the radio button problem

Comment: @VinuV: Always glad to help :) If this answer helped you solve your problem, please **[mark it as "accepted"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)**, so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to spot it easily.

Answer (score 1):

you have written

```
<form id="f1" method="post" action="2.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
```

Please put `name` attribute to the form tag "myForm" :-

```
<form id="f1" method="post" name = "myForm" action="2.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
```

Comment: thanks man,that solved the problem,it was really a headache..

Comment: @VinuV if you the solution then please accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

The id of your form and your script are different.

Change the form id/name to myForm

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" method="post" 
  action="2.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
```

JSBin Working Example: http://jsbin.com/exager/1/edit